# Save the output of the command in python dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-3.6

I have created a class to parse the output of the command and return the desired string.I have used regex to get the required string. The class in its current form servers the purpose. However, I'd like to make it more efficient by parsing the  entire command output and storing it in a dictionary.

Essentially,I want to split  the output based  on " : "  and store the entire output in the form of key value pair.

Output looks like below :

```
Interface: gig1
Profile: 
Session status: ACTIVE
Peer: x.x.x.x port 7500
  Session ID: 5
  v2 SA: local x.x.x.x/4500 remote x.x.x.x/4500 Active
  FLOW: permit 47 host 2.2.2.2 host 1.1.1.1
```

from test.ssh import Ssh
import re

```
class  crypto:
    def __init__(self, username, ip, password ,router):
       self.user_name = username
       self.ip_address =  ip
       self.pass_word = password
       self.machine_type = router

    def session_status(self, interface):
         command = 'show session '+interface
         router_ssh = Ssh(self.ip_address)
         result = router_ssh.cmd(command)
         search_obj = re.search("Session status:\s+(.*)", result, flags=0)
         return search_obj.group(1)
```

test script

```
from test.networks.router_parser import *

routerobj = crypto('user', 'ip', 'password', 'cisco')
status = routerobj.session_status('interface_name')
print (status)
```

Comment: do you want to store `result` in the form of dictionary based on `:`, we might need another splitter to key-value pair?

Comment: @be_good_do_good yes, I want to store the result from the command output in the form dictionary  based on :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
resultDict = dict(line.split(':', 1)
    for line in result.split('\n') if ':' in line)
```

To get rid of trailing and leading spaces:

```
resultDict = dict(map(str.strip, line.split(':', 1))
    for line in result.split('\n') if ':' in line)
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how to  access the dictionary from the test script. For instance, i want to print the session status in the test script .How do i do that? Also, what should the session_status () return ?

Comment: `print resultDict['Session status']` and `return resultDict['Session status']`.

Comment: Thanks, I want to return the entire output in the form of a dictionary and access the key value pair in the test script. So can i return the entire dictionary , return resultDict[ ]  . is this correct ?

Comment: Just `return resultDict` without brackets.   But do you really want to have a function called `session_status()` which returns more than the session status (and the whole dictionary instead)?  That sounds like a misnomer then.  How about `session_show_result()` instead?

Comment: yes,session_show_result() sounds correct. I will rename the func()